# Android SoundPool cutting sound file short

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm fairly new to Android so be gentle!

I have the following code, which should (I think) just play "developersshort".

```
public constructor(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    soundPoolMap.put(1, soundPool.load(this.context, 
        R.raw.developersshort, 1));         
}

public void run() {
    soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(1), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

[To try to figure out what's going on, it currently plays that remix of Steve Ballmer shouting "developers" repeatedly! The sound file is ~90KB in size.]

When I run my app in the emulator, and press the button to trigger the sound, it says "developers developers developers..." etc etc, like I would expect.

However, when I deploy it to my phone, all I hear something like "velop" once, and then the sound stops.

I have NO idea what is going on, any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is your audio file a .ogg file? It seems like other formats have issues with SoundPool. If that doesn't work you may want to test it with a smaller audio file. I had some glitches when my audio file was over 60kb.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with resampling the sound file ???

Before that my sound file getting cut. But i have converted and resample that m4a from 44KHz to 22KHz and now it works without getting cut. refer this : [and again about memory issues with SoundPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098138/and-again-about-memory-issues-with-soundpool)

So try like same.

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

60kb on storage, or 2mb on the heap, decoded, as pure wave MIGHT be the limits, yes.
make sure you dont use anything longer than a second or something like that.

soundpool really needs small files. read the SDK page.